Creative must provide enroll_status for standard enhancements while updating adset
When I am trying to update the targeting of an AdSet,  an error is returned.
Session URL : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/321102689698722/?session_id=1408717453113278
{
"error": {
"message": "Invalid parameter",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 100,
"error_subcode": 3858082,
"is_transient": false,
"error_user_title": "Creative Must Provide enroll_status for Standard Enhancements",
"error_user_msg": "This creative is eligible for Standard Enhancements, but enroll_status was not provided. Please choose whether you want to turn on standard enhancements or not. Learn more here: https://fburl.com/hyth50xo",
"fbtrace_id": "AEIUzfYUlrFTKB8KAgPcVoz"
}
}

But the enroll_status for Standard Enhancements is set in as OPT_IN for all the creatives inside the AdSet.
Session URL :  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/321102689698722/?session_id=425543010193929
[
{
"degrees_of_freedom_spec": {
"creative_features_spec": {
"standard_enhancements": {
"enroll_status": "OPT_IN"
}
}
},
"id": "120208488275990030"
}
]

It's not an advantage+ ad. It's happening for most of the objectives.
